# Subtracting data.frames and data.tables of different sizes

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

Two `data.frames` of same dimensions can be subtracted in `R` using

```
df1 - df2
```

But I want to subtract two `data.frames` of different dimensions like

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(V1=1:5, V2=6:10)

df1-df2

Error in Ops.data.frame(df1, df2) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

This subtracting can be achieved using for loop but I'm looking for any already established function. Thanks

**Edited**

How about if have to subtract two data.tables of different dimensions?

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(V1=1:5)
dt2 <- data.table(V1=1:5, V2=6:10)

dt1-dt2

Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, row(dt2), ) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #1611.
dt1[row(dt2),]-dt2
```

Comment: try `df1[row(df2),]-df2`

Comment: Or just `df1$V1-df2` in your case. But @akruns suggestions is probably more general

Comment: Excellent @akrun. This is more appropriate for my case. Thanks

Comment: I think though that if both `df1` and `df2` have more columns, it should be something like `unlist(df1[row(df2),])-df2`

Comment: @akrun: Please change your comment to answer and see my edits.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Please see my edits.

Comment: @akrun: Please change your comment to answer for future SO. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do this by making both the datasets have the same length so that we can compare element-by-element of each dataset.  In the example given 'df1' has 1 column with 5 rows, where as for 'df2' it is 2 columns with 5 rows.  The idea would be to make 'df1' having 10 elements or either 2 columns with 5 rows to match the dimensions of 'df2'.  This can be easily done by `rep` or a convenient function is `row`.

```
  df1[row(df2),]-df2
```

Just to make it more clear

```
 row(df2)
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    1    1
 #[2,]    2    2
 #[3,]    3    3
 #[4,]    4    4
 #[5,]    5    5
```

gives the row index for each row of 'df2'.  By doing

```
 df1[row(df2),]
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

we replicate each row element twice.  Given that the datasets do this in columnwise, it is happening like below

```
 df1[c(row(df2)[,1],row(df2)[,2]),]
```

This can be subtracted from `df2`

```
 df1[row(df2),]-df2
 #  V1 V2
 #1  0 -5
 #2  0 -5
 #3  0 -5
 #4  0 -5
 #5  0 -5
```

As @David Arenburg mentioned, this would return wrong results for both datasets having multiple columns.  So, if you are going to subtract a single column from 'df1' (having multiple columns) from a multiple column dataset ('df2'), then selecting that column and subtracting from 'df2' may be more general (Thanks to @David Arenburg's code)

```
 df1$V1-df2
 #  V1 V2
 #1  0 -5
 #2  0 -5
 #3  0 -5
 #4  0 -5
 #5  0 -5
```

It works due to the recycling effect, i.e. 'V1' column elements will subtract from the first column of 'df2', then it will again start from the first element to start subtracting from the second column of 'df2' (assuming that both datasets have the same number or rows).

---

For the second example with `data.table` (single column for 'dt1'), one option would be

```
dt1[,rep(names(dt1), ncol(dt2)),with=FALSE]-dt2
#   V1 V1
#1:  0 -5
#2:  0 -5
#3:  0 -5
#4:  0 -5
#5:  0 -5
```

Comment: I'm still troubled in how this is different from just `df1$V1-df2`? This solution won't work for lets say `df1 <- data.frame(V1=1:5, V2 = 6:10) ; df2 <- data.frame(V1=1:5, V2=6:10, V3 = 11:15)` unless wrapped into `unlist(df1[row(df2),])-df2`. Kind of confused regarding what OP actually wants.

Comment: @DavidArenburg In the example you provided, what is the expected output

Comment: The output from `unlist(df1[row(df2),])-df2` I'd guess, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg No idea.  I guess the OP might want to do the difference between each column of 'df1' with all the other columns in 'df2'.  (just a guess)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Do you remember Frank's code golfing to replicate columns in data.table.  Something like `dt1[] <- ..`

Comment: Yes, something like `dt1[] <- dt1$V1`

Comment: Either Way, your code will return an error on the provided data set, so I wondering why he can't just do `df1$V1-df2`

Comment: @DavidArenburg It will, but it is not clear whether the OP want to do that kind of operation with multiple columns in either dataset

Comment: Yes akrun and @DavidArenburg, I've multiple columns, and akrun's code works for me.

Comment: @akrun you can, I just don't understand what's going on

Comment: @MYaseen208 akruns solution works for you for this case `df1 <- data.frame(V1=1:5, V2 = 6:10) ; df2 <- data.frame(V1=1:5, V2=6:10, V3 = 11:15)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg For this example, something like `df1[row(df2), 1]-df2`

Comment: @akrun your solution is great, I just don't understand what OP is dealing with. eitherway, you can easily generalize your solution with `unlist(df1[row(df2),])-df2` as mentioned.

Comment: But `df1[row(df2), 1]-df2` will work only the first column so, again, you could do just `df1$V1-df2`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, that is what I thought the OP wanted.  But the `unlist` version from your example  `length(unlist(df1[row(df2),]))
#[1] 30` and `prod(dim(df2))#[1] 15` have different length.  I don't know what is the expected output